# VSTS fails to build Azure Service Fabric projects

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to set up a CI deployment of an Azure Service Fabric application in Visual Studio Team Services. I'm following the directions as outlined on this [documentation section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-set-up-continuous-integration).

My SF application consists of the base structure plus three Stateless Service C# application projects running console apps.

I've set up the build definition following the guidelines listed and the NuGet restore seems to work fine, but the next step, building the Solution, fails with the same error over and over again. The errors are all of the following pattern:

```
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "AutoMapper, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1820,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "AutoMapper, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\a\1\s\Workers\ImportWorker\ImportWorker.csproj]
For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
Considered "..\packages\AutoMapper.5.2.0\lib\net45\AutoMapper.dll", but it didn't exist.
For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
```

It goes on to list all the locations it tried and failed to find the DLL file. The Nuget restore step seems to be working fine, so I don't understand why it can't seem to find the packages.

I have several other projects in VSTS that all build just fine following the same pattern, but none of them are Azure Service Fabric apps, so I'm thinking it has something to do with that but I can't determine what and I've found very little to give me any ideas elsewhere.

One thing I tried was to create a brand new Service Fabric app with a single default Stateless app and when I try that on VSTS, it fails in exactly the same manner, which is why I'm guessing there's some issue around Service Fabric I haven't spotted.

Among my relevant VSTS settings, platform is set to x64 to match the SF project. 
VS version is set to Visual Studio 2015, which is what I'm using on the project. I have tried changing that to Latest Version, which didn't affect anything. For the MS Build architecture in the Solution build step I have tried both MSBuild x86 and MSBuild x64 with no variation in results.

The solution builds and runs just fine locally on the Service Fabric Local Cluster on my machine.

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, but there isn't a Stateless Service project installed AutoMapper package. There are Stateless Service, Statefull Service, Actor Service, Stateless Web APi, Guest Executable, Guest Container (Preview) and ASP.NET Core (Preview) templates, which template you used and which project uses AutoMap package? What's the detail build log? Can you share the project on the OneDrive?

Comment: The Automapper dll is just one example of DLLs referenced by my full project that is failing in VSTS. The Service Fabric solution has three Stateless Service projects within it which all have various referenced packages. VSTS build does not appear to be able to find any of those DLL files in any of the three projects in the solution. 
The empty default project I tried also failed to build the blank Stateless Service project, but it was some Service Fabric DLL it couldn't find. I don't recall now any by name. I discarded the blank project when I quit trying to find a resolution myself

Comment: Are you using a hosted agent or your own. If it's your own, make sure the Service Fabric SDK is installed on the agent.

Comment: @BBlake What're detail build steps of your build definition? Can you provide the detail build log here?

Comment: I'm using the VSTS hosted build agent. The build steps are exactly as outlined in the the doc page I referenced.  NuGet restore first, which appears to run fine, then Build solution, which fails. I'll try to get a log posted later.

Comment: @BBlake Does NuGet restore step restore necessary packages (check in log)? For build log, you can go to the detail page of a build, then click download all logs as zip, then share on the OneDrive.